# Cannot access Vue directive with npm link

Tags: vue.js, npm-link, vue-directives

I forked an npm module and would like to make some changes, test them locally and then open a pr.

I have two folders:

`~/projects/some_module-test` where I would like to run a Vue app to test my changes.

`~/projects/some_module` is the forked repo of `some_module`.

I ran `npm link` in `~/projects/some_module` and then `npm link some_module` in `~/projects/some_module-test`

In `main.js` of `some_module-test` I do the following:

```
const my_module = require("some_module")
console.log(my_module)

Vue.use(my_module)
```

When I log `my_module` I can see all the methods on it so `npm link` seems to work.

Unfortunately, I can not access the directives which should be supplied by `my_module` in `App.vue`

`<div @my_module_shortkey="['ctrl', 'a']" @my_module_directive='someAction()'/>`

This is my `vue.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false)
   }
}
```

Any input is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
import my_module from 'some_module'
Vue.use(my_module)
```

instead of

```
const my_module = require('some_module')
Vue.use(my_module)
```

did the trick.